# How to restrict bugzilla non-authorized access?

Tags: bugzilla

I have a `Bugzilla` server and I found a security issue. If I make logout on web interface I still can read bugs by direct link. Enumerating bug ID in the URL I can read **all** bugs already exists.
I was unable to found how to restrict access `Bugzilla` for unauthorized (not logged in) users?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because security issues from individual software should be adress to the respective developers not on this side as we do not maintaine this software

Comment: This is a question about QA/Testing software and its configuration.  I think its appropriate.

Comment: Better audience to ask this question would be Bugzilla mailing list. Part of guidance we should provide is that there are many questions related to QA which are better asked elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that this question is also oriented to administrators, not only to QA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop external access then one way is to set Apache Password Protected Directories with .htaccess File

This will mean any user accessing below a certain DIR level will require a password for access.  Please note, this access is independent from the access granted by Bugzilla

A simple instruction guide is available [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-apache-password-protect-directory-with-htaccess-file/)